# Raspberry Pi shows up rainbow screen on my VGA monitor, touch screen works fine

Tags: raspbmc, raspi-config

Monitor looks like this:

[image]

I am new to configuring Raspberry pi with VGA monitor.
My monitors resolution is 1366x768

I did the below configuration to my config.txt file

```
# Force the monitor to HDMI mode so that sound will be sent over HDMI cable
hdmi_drive=2
# Set monitor mode to DMT
hdmi_group=2
# Set monitor resolution to 1024x768 XGA 60Hz (HDMI_DMT_XGA_60)
hdmi_mode=16
# Make display smaller to stop text spilling off the screen
overscan_left=20
overscan_right=12
overscan_top=10
overscan_bottom=10
```

Operating system
rpi_35_v5_jessie8_kernel_4_1_19.rar

Raspberry pi also has a touchscreen which works perfectly. Below I have the configuration document.

http://osoyoo.com/wp-content/uploads/samplecode/rasp_lcd.pdf

Comment: Looks to me like the Pi is not ready, or the operating system isn't compatible with your version of Pi. What version of Pi have you got? Where did you get your operating system from? That filename isn't one I'm familiar with and doesn't sound like it was downloaded from raspberrypi.org which is where you _should_ be getting your OSs from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That normally means that the Raspberry Pi is not able to load your operating system. The hardware test has passed, but then unable to find or load the image.

The NOOBs image from the Raspberry Pi website is a version that you can just drag and drop onto the SD card, but for most other OS downloads you will normally have to extract the file and then write it as a raw file to the SD card.

I'd suggest sticking with the NOOBs install, unless you have a specific reason to need something else.

Comment: Thanks Stewart the NOOBs setup worked perfectly for me. I am trying to get the resolution to 1366 x 768 in place.

Comment: The resolution is set in config.txt and has to be edited by hand - it's a shame that they don't have that included in the raspi-config too.

You can edit directly on the Raspberry Pi eg.
sudo nano /boot/config.txt

or you can edit by taking the SD Card and putting it into a different computer - as the boot partition is visible as a FAT drive on most computers.

Details of the values you need are in the following link:
http://elinux.org/RPiconfig